# How to merge two pandas dataframes(A &B) , creating a new one excluding index that are on both dataframes(A & B)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, that i'll call ***A*** and ***B***.

The ***DF A***, has UsersId as index and **8000 rows and 9 columns** like this:

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 22 | 22 |
| bbb | 33 | 33 |
| **DEF** | **44** | **44** |

The ***DF B***, also has UsersID as index and **500 rows and 4 columns**, like this:

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ccc | 22 | 22 |
| ddd | 33 | 33 |
| **DEF** | **44** | **44** |

My question is, how do i merge those both dataframes into a new one and than **DELETE** the row with the **index def** ?

To be more clearer, i need my newDF like this:

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 22 | 22 |
| bcd | 33 | 33 |
| ghi | 22 | 22 |
| jkl | 33 | 33 |

This is how i want the new df, merged but with the index **DEF** and all row information deleted from it. Hope someone can help me :).The index on both tables is the UserID and it has different numbers of rows and columns, but same index.

Comment: This is called an `ANTI-JOIN`. Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you could simply concatenate the two dataframes as they are and then drop duplicates on index:

```py
newDF = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=False)
newDF = newDF[~newDF.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

When concatenating the two dataframes, `ignore_index = False` will preserve the indices of the original dataframes, so as to be able to drop them later on!